# What are the minimum privileges required for using mysqldump

Tags: mysql, privileges

I want to create mysql user with limited privileges to use only with `mysqldump`. What are minimum privileges that we can assign to user so he can just take dump and load databases or this requires admin rights ?

For now I have something like this working but I am not certain about the scope:

```
 DROP user 'dumpuser'@'localhost' ;
 FLUSH PRIVILEGES ;
 GRANT  SELECT ON mysql.proc TO  'dumpuser'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'dumppwd';
 GRANT  ALL ON dbname.* TO 'dumpuser'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'dumppwd';
 FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
```

I want to further limit privilege scope if possible.

Comment: To export the schemas it needs SELECT and LOCK access to information_schema, to export the data it needs view and lock table access to your database. It also needs to have SHOW VIEW to export any views, EVENT to export scheduled tasks, and TRIGGER to export and maintain triggers.

Comment: @scragar Why not make an answer out of your comment?

Comment: @hek2mgl because I have a horrible feeling I'm forgetting something important and don't want to post an answer that contains incorrect information by pretending this is an accurate list.

Comment: Seems you were right and accurate .. ;)

Comment: and for `--routines` requires the `SELECT` privilege for the `mysql.proc` table. I am still expecting a complete answer :)

Answer (score 6):

> mysqldump requires at least the SELECT privilege for dumped tables,
>   SHOW VIEW for dumped views, TRIGGER for dumped triggers, and LOCK
>   TABLES if the --single-transaction option is not used. Certain options
>   might require other privileges as noted in the option descriptions.

From http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/mysqldump.html